# File to Folder from terminal

Tags: 16.04

I am trying to move a file into a folder in Ubuntu using a terminal.
But I have no idea how to do this. Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`mv`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/mv.1.html) command:

```
mv "path of file" "path of folder"
```